# How can estimated means be bounded in a Gaussian mixture model?

Tags: scikit-learn, gaussian

I am using the scikit Gaussian mixture and I want to provide an initial mean guess and also some constrains in the search space.

I can set the `means_int` to what I need, but how can I limit the search space, for each gaussian, +/- some value. How can I do this? Is this set it in the `precisions_int`? I do not understand how to use it.

Example

```
models = GaussianMixture(n_components=5, covariance_type="spherical", tol=1e-4,max_iter=100,n_init=1,means_int=np.array([10,20,30,40,50]).fit(np.expand_dims(X,1))
```

Let's say that I do not want the mean of each Gaussian to vary more than +/- 2 from the initial condition.